# How do I change a dataframe's column that has numerical date to textual form?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a dataset like this

**Date** ----------**F/R**------**S/R**

9/22/2018 --- 72-------- 00

9/21/2018-----22---------17

Now what I'm trying to do is just I want to replace that date in textual format like for '9' I want 'September' and for the day '22' I want 'Saturday'.
First I tried changing the month from numerical to textual with this piece of code and failed

```
import pandas as pd


# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('teer1_new1.csv')

def f(x):
    if (x['Date']):
        if (x[0:1] == '9/'):
            return 'September'
    else:
        return 'none'

dataset['Date'] = dataset.apply(f, axis=1)
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

And yeah my dataframe date column has a lot of rows in it, for your reminder thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need convert dates to datetimes first - by parameter `parse_dates` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) or [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), last use [`Series.dt.month_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month_name.html) and 
[`Series.dt.day_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('teer1_new1.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
#alternative
#df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df['Date1'] = df['Date'].dt.day_name()
df['Date2'] = df['Date'].dt.month_name()
print (df)
        Date  F/R  S/R     Date1      Date2
0 2018-09-22   72    0  Saturday  September
1 2018-09-21   22   17    Friday  September
```

Comment: for this alternative #df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
console says the format doesn't match.
And If I run this alternative without format parameter then it goes all well.

Comment: @AdityaMandal - Then try `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

Comment: Yeah @jezrael I used it like that and it worked thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @AdityaMandal - I see there is no accepting my answer, there is some problem?

Comment: and yeah @jezrael what can I use if I want to get the year of date, I tried dt.year_name() and guess what it doesn't exist :/

Comment: @AdityaMandal - No problem, need `df['Date3'] = df['Date'].dt.year`

Comment: No, its good it does work, I thought I have already accepted it, sorry for that :) @jezrael

And thanks for all your help :)

Comment: Okay, your answer seem easy for other guys so I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @AdityaMandal - Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataset['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Date'])
## returns month
dataset['monthname'] = dataset['Date'].dt.month_name()
## returns day
dataset['day'] = dataset['Date'].dt.dayofweek()

## creating a map of dayofweek to day
s = {6 : 'Sunday', 0: 'Monday', 1: 'Tuesday', 
     2: 'Wednesday', 3: 'Thursday', 4: 'Friday', 5: 'Saturday'}
s = pd.Series(s)
dataset['dayname'] = dataset['day'].map(s)
```